# Is there a way to authenticate default login without user input/intervention and redirect to my designated page in MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I'm creating a web application that can access Client and Server Side. I have scenario that after login(Client side) I have a module called payment that can both have function of inter branch (server side)and local branch(client side) payment. Now my only problem is when I'm attempting to redirect to my inter branch page I end up redirect to my login page. How to redirect to my inter branch page in which I can bypass login or authenticate my login via background or something that no user intervention occur.

Comment: Your controller routes probably has some sort of authorization attribute `[Authorize]`, somewhere around the lines of that. If you want to bypass this during development, just delete it for now.

Comment: Please check this - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you for your reply @AbanaClara. But there is no authorization attribute [Authorize] on my routes controller. Also for the supporting details I'm using Form Authentication in all of my pages that added in my web.onfig.